# Why error on line 9 The Value of field _maintext isn't used?

Tags: flutter

I wrote a code with just 2 buttons that when pressed change the text on a centered card widget on screen. Worked fine. then tried to extract the 2 buttons to a different dart file in a different widdget (just for practice, I am a newbie) that will get called but it gives me green underline on line 9.

```
class Buttons extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonsState createState() => _ButtonsState();
}

class _ButtonsState extends State<Buttons> {
 String _maintext;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
                height: 200,
                child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50),
                    child: Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.white70),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    highlightElevation: 100,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _maintext = "Κι εγώ!";
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text("Ναι!!"),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.white70),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.do_not_disturb_on,
                      color: Colors.white70,
                    ),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
                    elevation: 50,
                    highlightElevation: 100,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _maintext = ":(";
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text("Οχι....."),
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.do_not_disturb_on,
                    color: Colors.white70,
                  )]));
  }}
```

Comment: which one is line 9? Maybe it's pointing to some typo. Red ones are errors, yellow or orange for warning and green is for typos in general

Comment: String _maintext; ->green underlines says that the value isn't used even though it is used right below.

Comment: you are just setting the value and not using it anywhere like `Text(_maintext)` that's why.

Comment: What if I dont want to use it here, but just take the "state" and input it on a different widget tree?

Comment: it's a warning and not an error, ides suggest these in case you assign variables and forget to use them.